# Unit Testing exported module functions

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Trying to unit test the functions inside an exported module with the help of `Jest`

The module is the following:

```
export default {

  errorNotification (title, text) {
    Vue.notify({
      group: 'max-fordham',
      type: 'error',
      title: title,
      text: text
    })
  },

  infoNotification (title, text) {
    Vue.notify({
      group: 'max-fordham',
      type: 'info',
      title: title,
      text: text
    })
  },

  successNotification (title, text) {
    Vue.notify({
      group: 'max-fordham',
      type: 'success',
      title: title,
      text: text
    })
  },

  warningNotification (title, text) {
    Vue.notify({
      group: 'max-fordham',
      type: 'warning',
      title: title,
      text: text
    })
  }
}
```

The test I'm trying to write is:

```
import notifications from '@/services/notifications.service'

describe('Notifications tests', () => {
  test('successNotification should set title to title and text to text ', () => {
    let title = 'test'
    let text = 'test'

    //let successNotification = jest.fn()

    notifications.successNotification(title, text)
    expect(title).toEqual('test')
    expect(text).toEqual('test')
  })
})
```

When I run this I receive the following error:

> TypeError: _vue.default.notify is not a function

Now, as far as I understand, the error is due to me not mocking `_vue.default.notify`, however, I am not sure how to actually do that. Some help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock `Vue` module manually using `jest.mock(moduleName)`.

For example:

`index.ts`:

```js
import Vue from './Vue';

export default {
  errorNotification(title, text) {
    Vue.notify({
      group: 'max-fordham',
      type: 'error',
      title: title,
      text: text
    });
  },

  infoNotification(title, text) {
    Vue.notify({
      group: 'max-fordham',
      type: 'info',
      title: title,
      text: text
    });
  },

  successNotification(title, text) {
    Vue.notify({
      group: 'max-fordham',
      type: 'success',
      title: title,
      text: text
    });
  },

  warningNotification(title, text) {
    Vue.notify({
      group: 'max-fordham',
      type: 'warning',
      title: title,
      text: text
    });
  }
};
```

`Vue.ts`: I create the `Vue` module to simulate the real `Vue` module.

```js
export default {
  notify(payload) {
    //
  }
};
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import notifications from './';
import Vue from './Vue';

jest.mock('./Vue.ts');

describe('Notifications tests', () => {
  test('successNotification should set title to title and text to text ', () => {
    Vue.notify = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce({});
    const title = 'test';
    const text = 'test';

    notifications.successNotification(title, text);
    expect(Vue.notify).toBeCalledWith({
      group: 'max-fordham',
      type: 'success',
      title,
      text
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58239972/index.spec.ts
  Notifications tests
    ✓ successNotification should set title to title and text to text  (12ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.773s
```